# how to add multiple types of translations in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate

I used this code 
to try and add a translation array from /resources/languages
ANd
to add a translation from /application/languages/nl.mo (gettext)

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
        array(

            'adapter' => 'array',
            'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/resources/languages',
            'locale'  => 'nl',
            'scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY
        )
    );


    $translate->addTranslation(
        array(
            'adapter' => 'gettext',
            'content' => APPLICATION_PATH.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'languages'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'nl_NL.mo',
            'locale'  => 'nl'
        )
    );
```

When i try to add a single translation everything works ok (in both cases)
When i'm adding a second translation i get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Translate_Exception' with
>   message 'Error including array or file
>   '1'' in
>   blabla.php
>   on line 61

can someone tell me how to add those translation files from my bootstrap, without getting these errors?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think you cannot mix types of translation files. The reason is that `$translate->addTranslation()` will actually call a method `addTranslation()` on `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Array`, which in turn will call a method `_loadTranslationData` also  on `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Array`. Thus `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Array` tries to read file `nl_NL.mo` as an array which results in **Error including array or file**  error.

However, if the translation file 'nl' is the one from zend resources, and you want to use it only for translating zend_form messages, I think you could define a separate translator for this as follows:

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
    array(

        'adapter' => 'array',
        'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/resources/languages',
        'locale'  => 'nl',
        'scan' => Zend_Translate::LOCALE_DIRECTORY
    )
);

 // use this one in Zend_Form 
 Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

And the 'nl_NL' you can make your default for the rest:

```
$translate = new Zend_Translate(
                array(
                    'adapter' => 'gettext',
                    'content' => APPLICATION_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'languages' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'nl_NL.mo',
                    'locale' => 'nl'
                )
);       

// Save it for the rest of application to use
Zend_Registry::set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
```

P.S.
I have not tested this, hence I cannot grantee it works, but this is how I would at least try to do it.

Comment: sounds like a good solution to me :), This afternoon i'll try. If it works i'll reward you with a accepted answer :)

Comment: unfortunatly the above example does not work. I think using different adapters do not work in Zend :(